# Stream throw exception in filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have defined this stream:

```
public int sumNumbers(int[] numbers) {
    return IntStream.of(numbers)
            .filter(n -> n <= 1000)
            .sum();
}
```

Where I'm summing all integers that are not higher than 1000. But now what I want to do is, throw an exception if any element of the array is negative.

I know how to do it in the old fashioned mode, but I was wondering if there's any mechanism with `Stream` and `.filter()` where I can define a filter and an exception case for that filter

Just to clarify I want to throw an exception, and not control a runtime exception as the other question does.

The idea here is that if my filter is true in:

```
filter(n -> n < 0 throw Exception)
```

Comment: Why not use `n >= 0 && n <= 1000`? Also, `Functional` by default doesn't support throwing checked exceptions.

Comment: The requirement it´s throw an exception to inform the wrong data, kinda weird that being so powerful does not allow something like this.

Comment: @TagirValeev you should post that comment as an answer (except `.peek(n -> {if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + n);}` is what OP wants)

Comment: @Bohemian, sounds reasonable. Done.

Comment: It’s not always the best to do everything in one operation. A good old pre-check is not bad. If it should be done with streams, you may use: `if(Arrays.stream(numbers).reduce((a,b) -> a|b).orElse(0)<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();`

Comment: If you *expect* negative numbers, you can simply test using `Arrays.stream(numbers).anyMatch(i -> i<0)`, but as we are talking about illegal arguments here, I wouldn’t consider them to be expected…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an `IllegalArgumentException` in JDK which is unchecked and informs about wrong function input, so it can be used here:

```
IntStream.of(numbers)
         .peek(n -> {
           if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(n));
         })
         .sum();
```

In general, currently Java develops towards unchecked-only exceptions. There's even `UncheckedIOException` class added in Java-8!